# How To include row when using HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 BiqQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigQuery table with 30+ columns and I want to SELECT * where session is unique.

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table.id`
WHERE session IN (
    SELECT session
    FROM `table.id`
    GROUP BY session
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

And it works, but I just learned from another question that `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` excludes the duplicate row:

> Note that DISTINCT is used to show distinct records including 1 record from duplicate too. On the other hand HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 is checking only records which are not duplicate.
> For a simple example, if session has : 1, 1, 2, 3
> DISTINCT will result in: 1, 2, 3
> HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 will result in: 2, 3

I need the `DISTINCT` result, the one that includes one entry of the duplicate.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance, kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [ROW_NUMBER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#numbering_function_concepts)?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY session) as row_num
  FROM `table.id`
)
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It does not work, when I run `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sessions)` it gives me 1023 entries, and when I run ```SELECT *FROM `table.id` WHERE session IN ( SELECT DISTINCT sessionFROM `table.id`)```

it gives me much more entries...

Comment: Maybe ROW_NUMBER then?